# maze problem and Recursive backtracker algorithm

Tags: algorithm, maze

i want to implement the Recursive backtracker algorithm to solve maze problem, but i cant understand 2.3 Command ("remove the wall between the current cell and the chosen cell") would any help me ?

1. Mark the current cell as 'Visited'
2. If the current cell has any neighbours which have not been visited

   1. Choose randomly one of the unvisited neighbours
   2. add the current cell to the stack
   3. remove the wall between the current cell and the chosen cell
   4. Make the chosen cell the current cell
   5. Recursively call this function
3. else

   1. remove the last current cell from the stack
   2. Backtrack to the previous execution of this function

Edit
In fact I want an algorithm to solve maze problem by using stack.

Comment: Where have you got this algorithm from? Presumably this is an attempt to solve a "real world" type maze with solid walls that can't be removed! Removing a wall would change the maze and therefore make a "maze solving" algorithm somewhat useless. There is also no other instruction to "put the wall back".

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm

Comment: ah so this is a maze generation algorithm not a maze solver. I got the impression from your question this was an attempt to solve an existing maze.

Comment: i actual want to find best way towar destintion. do think this is a proper algorithm ?

Comment: dev - you need a maze solving algorithm eg http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm

Answer (score 4):

That algorithm is a maze *generator* not a maze *solver*.  The idea is that you want to create a random maze.  You also want all points in the maze to be reachable from all other points.

If you just randomly remove walls it is likely that your maze will not be connected.  The recursive backtracking algorithm takes care of this by creating a random *walk* and removing the walls along that random walk.  The recursive backtracking part allows you to walk to every cell in the maze, even when you reach a dead end.

Comment: I think I am in wrong way.I want to solve maze by using stack, and then finding the best way and possible ways.

Comment: +1 for realising this is generation not solving! Took me by surprise too. Could do with retitling/rewording the question.

Comment: @persian dev - you need a maze solving algorithm eg http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm

Comment: In that case, just treat the maze like a graph and do a DFS (stack) or BFS (queue).

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is for `god` mode. Normally you should do

1. **If the current cell is the exit, then finished**
2. If the current cell has any neighbours which have not been visited **that are not walls**

   1. Choose randomly one of the unvisited **non-wall** neighbours
   2. add the current cell to the stack
   3. **nothing**
   4. Make the chosen cell the current cell
   5. Recursively call this function
3. else

   1. remove the last current cell from the stack
   2. Backtrack to the previous execution of this function

Comment: i use 0 for non-wall cells and 1 for wall cells like in the following array : {0,0,0} {0,0,1} ....

Comment: This algorithm is not for god mode, it is for maze generation.  god mode wouldn't require any randomization (and in fact your search algorithm doesn't either).

Comment: What do you mean by "wall cells"? each cell will have 4 walls although they will all (except the edges) be shared with other cells. I would say you need to record the top and right-hand cell walls (or North and East) if you prefer. These will be the bottom and left-hand (or South and West) walls of the two cells to the top and right respectively.

Comment: @El Ronnoco: it means that the whole cell is used as a wall.

Comment: @ruslik. Ah I see. So every other cell on each axis is a "room". Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the wall simply means removing the wall! You start with a grid of cells, each of which is totally surrounded by 4 walls. As you move randomly around (2.1) you remove the wall joining the cells.