# Logic behind a stack-based maze algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, depth-first-search, maze

I'm fairly new to C++ programming, and I'm working on a maze solving algorithm. I need to use an explicit stack to keep track of the moves of done, no recursion.

Basically I'm responsible for the "Solver" algorithm, I can check to see if a move is available or blocked and do it, or I can undo a move. The moves are left, right and forward. There is already code that takes care of drawing and updating the maze.

What I could use is just some help understanding the basic algorithm for traversing the maze. I've looked at a lot of different programs for doing it, but I just can't seem to figure it out. The maze I'm solving is generated randomly, with no loops.

Here is what I can't wrap my mind around: say I have a straight section of wall, but there's a branch coming out of the wall as well. Say I decide to go down this other branch, but eventually it leads to a dead end. I've pushed all the moves I've done onto the stack. Basically, how do I know how many moves I need to pop off the stack to know I'm back at the original junction, so I can take the other branch instead of the blocked one?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: “I need a stack … so no recursion” – this makes no sense. Care to explain?

Comment: possible duplicate of [maze problem and Recursive backtracker algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402846/maze-problem-and-recursive-backtracker-algorithm)

Comment: @Moo-Juice That's not a good duplicate. It's a maze-solving question, but the specific question is quite different.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You're right. What I meant was, we haven't worked with recursion yet, so our Solver algorithm shouldn't be recursive, but it is a stack based exercise as we just learned those.

Comment: @user2302335 Interesting and odd, from a didactic perspective, teaching recursion should absolutely come before teaching about the stack data structure. But never mind, the answer doesn’t change for this.

Comment: recursion is generally a bad idea, I don't know why they put it into young minds ...

Comment: @nhed Actually it isn't, unless you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @JohnKugelman, a fair point - my bad.

Comment: @Cubic in my experience it is never better ... so please educate me

Comment: @nhed Recursive solutions may be easier to read sometimes, and certain kinds of recursion can be optimized to loops anyway so there's no actual loss.

Comment: @Cubic if you will convert it to a loop, its no longer recursive.   On the other hand you are eating stack space, which can be much more limited (at least in some environments), so its only good for academic reasons, which goes back to my original point

Comment: @nhed Uhm... I'm not talking about me turning it into loops. I'm talking about tail call optimization, which let's you call functions in the tail position of other functions, in the recursive case without having to allocate any stack space at all. Save for java, all languages I've been working with so far support this (or at least the tail recursive case).

Comment: @Cubic the C/C++ code will have to be very specific to ensure that the tail call optimization actually can proceed, the last thing in the function need to be the recursion (right?)  so we now have code that will behave well when first written (maybe) and then will go wacko on the stack if someone else modifies it for functionality or debug ... a maintenance nightmare IMHO,  I think we have to just agree to disagree

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Here is what I can't wrap my mind around: Say I decide to go down this other branch, but eventually it leads to a dead end. I've pushed all the moves I've done onto the stack. Basically, how do I know how many moves I need to pop off the stack to know I'm back at the original junction, so I can take the other branch instead of the blocked one?

All you need to do is always make the choices in a predefined order.

> The moves are left, right and forward.

If you always make those choices in that order, you'll know what you've already done when you backtrack.

**Each step** you backtrack, check those moves again.  If you're undoing a *right* choice, you'll know that you've tried *left* and *right*, but haven't yet tried *forward*.

Comment: It's a good solution with minimal memory footprint. But I got the feeling that using a stack was part of the question.

Comment: @Agentlien: there is a stack here. To undo a choice you must remember it. And you made lot of choices to come to the point you are.

Comment: @MathieuM. Let me clarify: while this does explain the logic behind what needs to be done, and it should be implemented using a stack, I feel it skips over how and why the stack comes into the picture. I felt this was an integral part of what the OP seemed to want clarification on.

Comment: @Agentlien hopefully the OP will clarify if the stack usage is unclear. My impression from the question is that pushing and popping moves is understood.

Comment: Thanks so much all for the very helpful feedback! I was thinking too far ahead of myself, now I've got the algorithm figured out. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To start off, add all possible moves from the starting position. Then, just follow this algorithm:

At every iteration, try to pop a single frame off the stack. If the stack was empty, you have tried all possible moves.

Now, look at the position you popped from the stack. This is your current position.

Add all moves from the position you popped which lead to unexplored positions to the stack. If any of them is a goal position, you're done.

The rest will take care of itself. Give it some thought, try a few cases on paper, you'll see. :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have many solutions: basically, exploring a maze with no loop is like doing a *depth first search* on the **covering tree**, each intersection being a node.

You can build the tree as you go, and use that information to walk through it, but this will be tedious an *not very efficient*.

A common method of depth first search is to push all the nodes to be checked on the stack, pull one, and push again, until you reach the goal. But you get a lot of nodes stacked up, and once you found the target node, you cannot use the stack to know which path you've followed, which means that you need to store that information elsewhere.

It is probably better to keep the stack solution and **tag the nodes** in your stack to indicate a branch, **and which direction** (ie. which subtree) of the branch have been *explored* (or which paths are left). If you do the exploration always in the **same order**, that tag can simply be a number:

- 0 for left
- 1 for front
- 2 for right
- 3 for backtrack

or better yet an enum.

When a dead end is found, just unwind the stack till you find one of these nodes, and try a new direction. If all directions have been tried, in other words if there's no direction left, unwind again.

```
enum Branch {
   LEFT,
   FORWARD,
   RIGHT,
   BACKTRACK
};

struct BacktrackException{
};

template <typename MazeMove>
struct StackNode {
    MazeMove move;
    Branch branch;
    StackNode(MazeMove m): move(m), branch(LEFT) {}
    MazeMove nextBranch(){
        switch(branch){
            case LEFT:
                if (move.can_left()){
                    branch = FORWARD;
                    return move.left();
                }
            case FORWARD:
                if (move.can_forward()){
                    branch = RIGHT;
                    return move.forward();
                }
            case RIGHT:
                if (move.can_right()){
                    branch = BACKTRACK;
                    return move.right();
                }
            default:
                throw BacktrackException();
        }
    }
};
```

The above code provide a wrapper for a possible "MazeMove" class used with the stack, which keeps track of the attempted direction. The nextBranch method returns the next possible move, or throws an exception.

The advantage is that your stack doesn't get clobbered with untried moves. You push a `StackNode` each time you reach a new position, and unwind it when its options have been all tested out. When you reach the maze exit, your stack contain only the  needed moves.

Answer (score 0):

> Basically, how do I know how many moves I need to pop off the stack to know I'm back at the original junction, so I can take the other branch instead of the blocked one?

You don’t – you always go back exactly *one* step. Then check all (remaining) alternatives, then go back one step further … etc. This is called [backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking).

By the way, this is identical whether you use recursion or not. Using recursion just makes the stack implicit, and the stack handling automatic.